# Ubuntu does not mount other partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have dualbooted ubuntu 14.04 together with Windows 8.1. i wanted to extend the partition for ubuntu so i used gparted. i moved a partition to the left then restarted, i was unable to extend the ubuntu partition and also ubuntu does not mount the other partitions. what might be the problem? kindly help.

Comment: Could you append your question with the output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: Why, if I may ask? I never heard that before.

Answer (score 2):

When Gparted tried to resize the Windows partition (I understood that it is the partition you talk about) probably it gone in some trouble and the NTFS is now on a "broken" state that needs you to restart it using Windows to correct the situation.

On that scenario, mount is not going to work until you start the partition with Windows to correct it, as a NTFS Linux-mount could damage more the file system there.